# create a function for barchart and call it in a loop and save all graphs

Tags: r, loops, plot

I need help to barplot multiple files in a loop. I have created a function to barplot these different files for only two columns out of 5 columns input file contains and then call the function

```r
bar.plot <- function( col_name1, col_name2,input_file, lable1, lable2) { 
  
  barplot(col_name1, names.arg = col_name2, xlab = "label1", ylab = "lable2",
          col= "blue", main = "bar plot of average", border = "red")

  box()
    
}
    
#call the function for 10 files
i <- 1
    
for (i in 1:10) {

  filename <- paste("C:/Users/admin/GoogleDrive/Vidya/R/document/Group_", 
                    i, ".csv", sep = "")
  group <- read.csv(filename)
  
  lablex <- "average"
  labley <- "master id"
      
  bar.plot(group$total_pause_time, group$employee_id, group, lablex, labley)
    
}
```

output plot shows `xlable` as label1 and `ylable` as label2, even though I have entered "**average**" in `lablex` and "**master id**" in `labley`.
Also tell me how to save these different plots with 10 diffrent names e.g. `plot1.jpg` to `plot10.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a pdf file of your ten individual plots

```
    bar.plot <- function( col_name1, col_name2,input_file, lable1, lable2)
{ 
  barplot(col_name1,names.arg = col_name2,xlab=label1,ylab=label2,
col= "blue",main = "bar plot of average",border = "red")
  box()
  }

#call the function for 10 files
label1 <- "average"
label2 <- "master id" 

setwd("C:/Users/admin/GoogleDrive/Vidya/R/document/Group_/")
filename <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
myfiles <- lapply(filename, read.csv)

  for (i in myfiles)
    {
    group    <- data.frame(myfiles[i])
    jpeg(paste(i,".jpg"))
  bar.plot(group$total_pause_time,group$employee_id,label1,label2)
  dev.off()
  }
```

[image: Sample plot]

Comment: hi, this code saves all plots in a single pdf but still lables are not coming as "average and "master id"

Comment: @vidyanair hope this may helpful for you

Comment: kumar ok..i will try

Comment: @vidyanair updated as per your jpeg plot for each and individual plot

Comment: @arun..it is working fine thanks..one more thing..how i can increment main = "..." with respect to i .. e.g. for barplot of average1, barplot of average2........barplot of average10

Comment: @vidyanair In your function replace main = paste("bar plot of average",i)

Comment: if these files , group1 to group10 are already shown in global environment then there is no need to do read.csv..in this case how to do it..means i directly want to import these files from global environment simultaneously increase their names lfom group1 to group10

Comment: @vidyanair Check it once

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bar.plot <- function( col_name1, col_name2,input_file, lable1, lable2) {
barplot(col_name1,names.arg = col_name2, xlab = lable1, ylab = lable2,
col= "blue",main = "bar plot of average",border = "red")
box()
}

#call the function for 10 files
for (i in 1:10){
filename <-paste("C:/Users/admin/GoogleDrive/Vidya/R/document/Group_",i,".csv",sep = "")
    group    <- read.csv(filename)
lable1 <- "average"
lable2 <- "master id"
bar.plot(group$total_pause_time,group$employee_id, group, lable1, lable2)
dev.copy(jpg,paste("C:/Users/admin/GoogleDrive/Vidya/R/document/plot",i,".jpg)
dev.off()
}
```

Comment: not working..still showing lable1 and lable2 instead of "average" and "master id"..and jpg not saved..

Comment: if these files , group1 to group10 are already shown in global environment then there is no need to do read.csv..in this case how to do it..means i directly want to import these files from global environment simultaneously increase their names lfom group1 to group10